# C++ recvfrom timeout

Tags: c++, sockets, recvfrom

I need to implement following behavior: when server starts, it should check for existing servers using broadcast. Then it waits for answer.

But, how to set any timeout for waiting?

```
int optval = 1;
char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
SOCKADDR_IN addr;
int length = sizeof(addr);

if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&optval, sizeof(optval)) == SOCKET_ERROR) throw(errors::SETSOCKOPT);

addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_port = htons(this->serverPort);
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sendto(s, this->serverName.c_str(), this->serverName.length() + 1, NULL, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

memset(&addr, NULL, sizeof(addr));

recvfrom(s, buff, BUFF_SIZE, NULL, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &length);
```

Comment: You can use `select(2)`, or set it in non blocking and use `epoll (2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a read timeout with `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVTIMEO`, and handle `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` which occurs if the timeout is triggered.

Comment: SO_RCVTIMEO works only for recv() , or not? This tells here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It works for any of the `recv()` family of methods, and also for `read()` except in Winsock systems.

Comment: @user207421 How do we 'handle' the `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` as I have set the timeout but my `recvfrom` seems to be ridiculously slow

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to use `select()` or `poll()` to wait for an event on a set of filedescriptors. These functions also allow you to specify a timeout. In your case, add the following before the `recvfrom()` call:

```
struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = s, .events = POLLIN};
poll(&pfd, 1, 1000);
```

This will wait 1000 milliseconds. This will exit when a packet has arrived on socket `s`, or after 1 second, whichever comes first. You can check the return value of `poll()` to see if it returned because of a packet or because of a timeout.

Comment: Right idea, unfortunately with the designated initializer list you trip over one of the syntax differences between C and C++.

Comment: @user4581301: it's valid in both C99 and C++11.

Comment: There was talk about slipping it into C++14, but as of C++17 drafts I'm still not seeing it in [dcl.init.aggr]. GCC appears to offer it as an extension.

Comment: Though it looks like some wording was changed to explicitly state what happens to `revents` if you `struct pollfd pfd = {s, POLLIN};`.  reads like it is treated as ``struct pollfd pfd = {s, POLLIN, {}};`` which should give 0.